# SQL Boolean Column Default Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Someone gave me this code:

```
select * from table where is_active
```

Is the is_active column, despite not having been set to anything, set to TRUE by default? Does the above query mean this:

```
select * from table where is_active = TRUE
```

It appears so, but couldn't find anything in the PostgreSQL documentation, so just wanted to confirm.

Comment: both queries will return the same result. All expressions in the where will be checked if they're `true` :)

Comment: `where` clause expects a boolean (logical) expression. `is_active` is one itself. `is_active = TRUE` is the same but more or less a tautalogy. Same with `not is_active` and `is_active = FALSE`

Comment: It's here in the PostgreSQL docs: where condition is **any** expression that evaluates to a result of type boolean. .... see: [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#:~:text=where%20condition%20is%20any%20expression%20that%20evaluates%20to%20a%20result%20of%20type%20boolean.%20Any%20row%20that%20does%20not%20satisfy%20this%20condition%20will%20be%20eliminated%20from%20the%20output.%20A%20row%20satisfies%20the%20condition%20if%20it%20returns%20true%20when%20the%20actual%20row%20values%20are%20substituted%20for%20any%20variable%20references.)

Comment: Yes, but I was expecting "is_active  = True" not just the column by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are right here. When the system looks at this query `select * from table_name where col1>col2`, it tries to find effective boolean expression after where clause, and ends up evaluating the expression to either true or false. But since the column value is already boolean so there is no need for that. `select * from table where is_active` is infact better. This is true for all SQL languages